# @salesforce/site/Id Invalid usage Issue in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, community, lightning-experience, experience-cloud, omnistudio

```
import siteId from "@salesforce/site/Id";
```

When I add the above import code in lwc component and add it to the Salesforce console App and refresh the page the component doesn't load and the error i see in console is:

**"Unsupported site Context, Invalid usage of @salesforce/site"**

However, I added required targets in meta.xml

```
<target>lightning__AppPage</target>
<target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
<target>lightning__HomePage</target>
<target>lightningCommunity__Page</target>
<target>lightningCommunity__Default</target>
```

**I am trying to figure out a way to know if the logged in user viewing the LWC Component is in the experience site or salesforce console app to conditionally show some data.**

If I can't use this site module for this purpose, what is the workaround?

I tried docs and other dev platforms but no use.